# Java Swing create a Text Area for the Output

Tags: java, swing, textarea, output

Hello I am really new to Java programming and I have created a Java menu with some options as well as file chooser. Therefore in my IDE I print out the file name and the path of the file that the user chooses. Is there any way that I can create a text area on my frame so the user can see the actual output ?
This is how my file chooser looks like and how I output the results on my console.

```
   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
       File F = new File("C:/");
       File namedir;
       File namepath;    
       chooser.setCurrentDirectory(F);
       chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
       chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose file to play");
       chooser.setApproveButtonText("Play");
       namedir = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
       namepath = chooser.getSelectedFile();
       System.out.print("the name of the the directory is "+namedir.getName());
       System.out.print("the name of the the path is "+namepath.getAbsolutePath());
```

And here is the code for my menu

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Menu");
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(600,400);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//add the menu bar with the item browse
JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
frame.setJMenuBar(bar);
JMenu search = new JMenu("Browse");
bar.add(search);
```

What I need is a text area so I can output the file name and the path on my frame.

Comment: Use JTextArea... setText according to what you want and simple add that area into your frame.

Answer (score 2):

See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), this explains the use of JTextArea. It is very simple and you can do alot of things using it. It will surely work for you.